# how get the return value in javascript promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to read a file and I want that logic to be inside a function, I did - that is below, I see I should get the result in terms of promise object, but I am not sure, the below code output `undefined`. Please tell how to fix this one ?

```
 var fs = require('fs');


 function readAppData() {
        var content;
        fs.readFile('app-lock.json', function read(err, data) {
            if (err) {  console.log(err); }
            try {

                content = JSON.parse(data);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }).then(t => {return content});

    }

    console.log(readAppData())
```

Comment: This is not how to use promises. Seems like you dont want to have async file reading. the FS library supports sync calls: `fs.readFileSync`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to *await* the promise that was made:

```
function readAppData() {
    return new Promise(function(res,thr){
    fs.readFile('app-lock.json', function read(err, data) {
        if (err) { thr(err);}
        try {
            res(JSON.parse(data));
        } catch (err) {
            thr(err);
        }
    })
    })
}

(async function(){
   console.log(await readAppData())
})()
```

Comment: this one works, I prefer to get the return object like this `readAppData()
.then(data=>{console.log(data)}, err=> {console.log(err)});`